# When using finalfit to create a table, is there a means of suppressing the 'label' and 'levels' headings?

Tags: r

I have compiled a table of summary statistics using finalfit, and then tidied it up a bit with kable. I attach a screenshot of some of the table.

Something I would like to do is suppress two of the default headings: 'label' and 'levels'. I know there's an option to assign 'label' with the label of the dependent variable (add_dependent_label=TRUE), but I can't see a way of suppressing text completely.

Any ideas?

In case it's helpful, I include below the code used for creating the table:

```html
# Copy the source data and then use the copy.
treatment_dataset <- loaded_data

# Turn variables into factors rather than integers, where necessary. 
# Label variable categories at the same time.
treatment_dataset$TREATMENT_GROUP <- factor(treatment_dataset$TREATMENT_GROUP,
  levels = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  labels = c("No primary surgery or chemotherapy", 
             "Primary surgery followed by anti-cancer therapy", 
             "Neo-adjuvant chemotherapy followed by interval surgery", 
             "Chemotherapy therapy only", 
             "Primary surgery only")
  )

treatment_dataset$AGE_GROUP <- ordered(treatment_dataset$AGE_GROUP,
  levels = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  labels = c("0-29", 
             "30-39", 
             "40-49", 
             "50-59", 
             "60-69", 
             ">=70")
  )

treatment_dataset$STAGE <- ordered(treatment_dataset$STAGE,
  levels = c(1,3,4,99),
  labels = c("I", 
             "II-III", 
             "IV", 
             "Not recorded")
  )

treatment_dataset$IMD_QUINTILE <- ordered(treatment_dataset$IMD_QUINTILE,
  levels = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  labels = c("Quintile 1 (least deprived)", 
             "Quintile 2", 
             "Quintile 3", 
             "Quintile 4", 
             "Quintile 5 (most deprived)")
  )

treatment_dataset$PERFORMANCESTATUS <- ordered(treatment_dataset$PERFORMANCESTATUS,
  levels = c(0,1,2,3,4,99),
  labels = c("0", 
             "1", 
             "2", 
             "3", 
             "4", 
             "Not recorded")
  )

# Label the variables
treatment_dataset %>%
  mutate(
    TUMOUR_CODE       = ff_label(TUMOUR_CODE, "Tumour site"),
    MORPHOLOGY        = ff_label(MORPHOLOGY, "Tumour morphology"),
    STAGE             = ff_label(STAGE, "Stage at diagnosis"),
    AGE_GROUP         = ff_label(AGE_GROUP, "Age at diagnosis (years)"),
    IMD_QUINTILE      = ff_label(IMD_QUINTILE, "English Index of Multiple Deprivation, income component (quintiles)‡"),
    CHARLSON          = ff_label(CHARLSON, "Charlson comorbidity index§"),
    PERFORMANCESTATUS = ff_label(PERFORMANCESTATUS, "Performance status at diagnosis"),
    CANALLIANCE_NAME  = ff_label(CANALLIANCE_NAME, "Cancer Alliance at diagnosis"),
    TREATMENT_GROUP  = ff_label(TREATMENT_GROUP, "Treatment group")
  ) -> treatment_dataset

# Create the explanatory and dependent columns for the table
explanatory = c("TUMOUR_CODE", "MORPHOLOGY", "STAGE", "AGE_GROUP", "CANALLIANCE_NAME", "CHARLSON", "IMD_QUINTILE", "PERFORMANCESTATUS")
dependent = "TREATMENT_GROUP"

# Create the table as t1
# Significance tests: Chi-squared for categorical, Kruskal-Wallis/Mann-Whitney for continuous
#treatment_dataset %>%
summary_factorlist(treatment_dataset, dependent, explanatory, 
  p=TRUE, 
  na_include=TRUE, 
  total_col = TRUE, 
  add_dependent_label = FALSE) %>% 
 ff_column_totals(treatment_dataset, 
                  dependent, 
                  label="Total tumours (N, %)*"
                  ) -> t1

# Format t1 using kable.
kable(t1) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", 
                                      "hover", 
                                      "condensed", 
                                      "responsive", 
                                      font_size = 8,
                                      fixed_thead = T)
                ) %>%
 add_header_above(c(" " = 2, 
                    "Treatment groups†" = 5, 
                    " " = 2)
                 )  %>%
 pack_rows("Tumour characteristics", 2, 17) %>%
 pack_rows("Patient demographics", 18, 54) )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do this.

```
library(finalfit)
explanatory = c("age", "age.factor", "sex.factor", "obstruct.factor")
dependent = "mort_5yr"
colon_s %>%
  summary_factorlist(dependent, explanatory) %>% 
  dplyr::rename(" " = label) %>% 
  dplyr::rename(" " = levels) %>% 
  knitr::kable(row.names = FALSE, align = c("l", "l", "r", "r"))
```

[image]